# JTable not adding a value on the first cell

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I am having to create a project that analyzes an HTML file and determine whether it is correct. If so, I must fill a table with the tags and how many there are.

During a test, with a successful file. The JTable was filled with the values, but the first cell was missing.

[a picture that shows my JTable missing the first cell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mLYlB.png)

"<HTML>" should be there instead of the nothing.

```
private void preencherTabela(ListaEstatica<String> tagsLista) {
        String[] tags = new String[tagsLista.getTamanho()];
        int[] qtTags = new int[tagsLista.getTamanho()];
        int tamanho = 0;
        for(int j = 0; j < tagsLista.getTamanho(); j++) {
            boolean isUnique = true;
            int indexRepetido = 0;
            for(int i = 0; i < tags.length; i++) {
                if(tagsLista.obterElemento(j).equals(tags[i])){
                    indexRepetido = i;
                    isUnique = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if(isUnique) {
                tags[tamanho] = tagsLista.obterElemento(j);
                qtTags[tamanho] = 1;
                tamanho++;
            } else {
                qtTags[indexRepetido] = qtTags[indexRepetido] + 1;
            }
        }
        Object[][] listaLinhas = new Object[tamanho][2];
        int k = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < listaLinhas.length; i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j < 2; j++){
                if (j == 0)
                    listaLinhas[i][j] = tags[k];
                if (j == 1)
                    listaLinhas[i][j] = qtTags[k];
            }
            k++;
        }
        tabelaAnalise.setModel(new DefaultTableModel(listaLinhas, new String[]{"Tag", "Número de Ocorrências"}));
    }
```

I've checked the Object[][] for any null values, but all of them were there.

[All items of the array](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8KiI9.png)

Note that I am using a list called "ListaEstatica", which we developed during class and must use, instead of regular Java Lists. This one is almost a copy of ArrayList, with "obterElemento", being the get method, "getTamanho" being the length.

Comment: *""`<HTML>`" should be there instead of the nothing."* The default renderer for a table is a `JLabel`. A label will interpret that HTML element as meaning that whatever follows should be rendered *as* HTML (& thus not display the HTML element itself).

Comment: @AndrewThompson I understand, but how could I avoid this? I've tried using \, but it just returns the cell with ```\<HTML>``` instead of ```<HTML>```

Comment: I just removed the angle brackets. Thank you @AndrewThompson